# $A\subseteq B$ if and only if $B'\subseteq A'$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

- $A\subseteq B$ if and only if $B'\subseteq A'$ ($A'$ means that complement of $A$, $B'$ is similar)

Proof trying. $(\subseteq)$. Let $x\in A\subseteq B$. Then, $x\in B$. $A'$ means that $U\backslash A$={$x'\in U$ and $x'\not\in A$}. **So, what should I do? Can you help?**

Comment: $A\subseteq B$ is already assumed for forward implication. Instead, fix $x\in B'$ and attempt to show $x\in A'$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say $A\subseteq B$ and take any $x\in B'$. Then $x\notin B$ and therefore $x\notin A$, since $A$ is subset of $B$. So $x\in A'$ and since $x$ is arbitrary we have $B'\subseteq A'$.

And vice versa.

Comment: Actually, I didn't understand your last statement that ''since $x$ is arbitrary we have $B'\subseteq A'$'', Why we have $B'\subseteq A'$ directly, why not  $A'\subseteq B'$.  I didn't this that can you explain this?

Comment: Where do you know this directly?

Comment: Since every (=arbitrary ) $x$ from $B'$ is also in $A'$ thus $B'$ is subset of $A'$.

Comment: Is it by the definition?

Comment: I still don't understand

Comment: Do you now what is a definition of the subsets?

Answer (score 0):

> Let $x\in A\subseteq B$. Then, $x\in B$

$x\in A\subseteq B$ makes no sense: $A\subseteq B$ is a statement about sets, not a set itself.

$A\subseteq B$ says that *if* $x \in A$, then $x \in B$.

Now you need to show that it follows from that that *if* $x \in B'$, then $x \in A'$

Comment: Where do we know that if $x\in B'$, then $x\in A'$?

Comment: @Kahler Well, if $x \in B'$, then $x \not \in B$ ... so can it be that $x \in A$, given that if $x\in A$ then $x \in B$?